# Make custom find in Microsoft Excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Excel file which has thousands of rows. My problem is I need to find some values in rows that do not contain the same value. This is a screenshot of my Excel rows.

[image: screenshot of my excel worksheet]

In those rows there are columns called **CODE** and **NAME**. Most values in the CODE column have **ST** as the first and second character. But, as you can see, there are some codes that do not not begin with **ST** (I highlighted them in yellow).

I would to find the values in the **CODE** column which do NOT contain **ST**. How could I make custom find to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't do this with `FIND`. But you could use the `FILTER`-option of Excel. Apply a auto-filter to your table. In the dropdown of column "A" you can choose "contains not", there you enter "ST". So you get only these rows, where the code starts not with "ST".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `FIND` you could use `Conditional Formatting` to highlight the cells as you did in your question for the sample cells.

**To apply conditional formatting**

Select all cells in column A.

On the `Home` tab, in the `Styles` group, click `Conditional Formatting` and select `New Rule...`

In the dialog box, click `Use a formula to detemine which cells to format`

In `Format values where this formula is true` type the formula

```
=LEFT(A2, 2)<>"ST"
```

(the `A2` in the formula refers to the top cell of the selected range, but the rule will be applied with correct cell references in all other selected cells)

Click `Format` and select `Yellow` in the `Color` box

Finally click OK until back to the worksheet.

**To clear conditional formattings**

On the `Home`tab, in the `Styles` group, click `Conditional Formatting`

Select `Clear Rules` and either `Clear from selected cells` or `Clear from entire sheet`